# Python etree iterparse in-stream editing of XML

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML data stream that is too large to fit in memory. I would like to scan the data and modify some elements “on-the-fly”. I can use the iterparse component of xml.etree to extract things but I can’t see how to write all of the nodes, modified and un-modified alike, to an output file.

Comment: Can you read line by line, and then write line by line after modification.

Comment: The input stream is not pretty printed: no extraneous white space and no new-line characters, so it’s difficult to read it line by line.

Comment: Is it possible to judge the starting and ending position of the complete label by block reading?

Comment: My data contains a number of <parameter> elements that are used in a lot of different places for a lot of different purposes. A subset of them will have a name attributes with a value of, say, “red”, “green”, or “blue”. For those, I need to replace “red” with “cyan“ in the name, title and description attributes, and make similar changes for green and blue. If the name is “black”, the entire elemenet and its children should be deleted. Each of the  <parameter> elements and its children is less than a 1,000 characters in size.

Comment: It sounds like it can be read block by block. You can post a simple XML file as an example.

Comment: So, you are suggesting that I simply read a block of data and scan it for “<parameter “. If I find that, I make sure that I have at least 1,000 characters following it and then extract and process just that element. I’ll need to keep the last 11 characters of my buffer, in case it ended with “<paramet” or something, append the next block, and repeat. Not very pretty, but I guess I can write a generator to hide the ugly bits.

Comment: You can try it.